# c# winform control access modifiers

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding a button to a winform programmatically and wish this to be public.  I can't see any option to set this programmatically.

Does anybody know how?

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding it programmatically? Are you adding it at design time, or run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add it to a form problematically you need to expose it yourself

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
  public MyForm()
  {
    InitializeComponenents();

    MyButton = new Button { Text = "GO" } ;
    this.Controls.Add(MyButton);
  }

  public Button MyButton { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, it should be "InitializeComponent();" not "InitializeComponenents();".

Comment: I wonder if the fact you wrote "problematically" means anything :)

Comment: @Ran: I should have programmatically of course, I have no idea what I was thinking of :)

Comment: Upvote because it is answering the question, even if I dont like it. This takes away the possibility to add multiple controls dynamically. I mean an unknown number of controls all set to public. :(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have confused between adding a button to a form, and adding a member to a class. Or maybe just didn't ask the question clearly enough.

If by "adding a button to a winform programmatically", you meant that you have a `Form` with code that does something like:

```
var b = new Button();
this.Controls.Add(b);
```

then there is not such thing as making it `public`, because the new button is not a member of your form class.

At any rate, it is not recommended to expose buttons as public properties of a Form, because this breaks the Form's abstraction and exposes internal implementation. It is better to expose the required *functionality* through properties and methods, but avoid making the button itself public.

Comment: If you drag a Button to a Form within the VS design time editor it will be stored as a private member var within the *.Designer.cs file; private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1; If you look in Form.Controls it has a reference to that Button which is private. He wants it public as you would change it within the Modifiers property within the VS editor

Comment: @Aaron: I know, but where does the "programmatically" part come in? When someone says he's adding a button programmatically, that usually means through code in runtime. Not through UI in design time...

Comment: Yes it does mean through code at runtime...he wanted to do what you can do at design time within the VS editor by changing the "Modifiers" property which is exposed within the editor; which is why I Was providing the VS explanation more in depth as my guess was the OP wanted to mimic that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
public class myOwnForm : Form
{
  public Button myOwnButton;
  public myOwnForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    myOwnButton = new Button();
    myOwnButton.Text = "Click Me!";
    myOwnButton.Size = new Size(50,50);
    myOwnButton.Location = new Point(100,100);
    Controls.Add(myOwnButton);
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 That will not make the myOwnButton publicly accessible outside of myOwnForm

Comment: Yes this will work; however creating all your buttons as class level variables is not very dynamic; might as well add them within the VS editor and hide them. I am unable to remove my downvote unless answer is edited; otherwise I would...